# Add filter in Gmail to recognize resent mails

Tags: gmail

I have set up my Hotmail to forward all e-mails to my Gmail account.
When I look at the original messages in Gmail, in the headers I see a `Resent-from: ...@hotmail.com`.

Is there a possibility to add a filter to recognize all these e-mails